# tms-like Time Machine backup utility for Snow Leopard?

Tags: macos, mac, time-machine

I'm looking for a tool like [`tms`](http://fernlightning.com/doku.php?id=software:misc:tms#description) that I can use to browse files on a Time Machine backup (on a Time Capsule) of another computer. `tms` is apparently "expired" and refuses to work on Snow Leopard.

Comment: Just read on their website: *Sep '10: We plan to release a non-beta 1.0 version that runs on 10.6 within the next few months along with a UI*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without actually reading all capabilities of `tms`:

- To see the Time Machine galaxy for another Mac: hold down Option while clicking the Time Machine icon, to see *Enter Time Machine* change into *Browse Other Time Machine Disks*.
- Command line tool to see what's been backed up: [timedog](http://code.google.com/p/timedog/).
- Likewise, for a GUI: [TimeTracker](http://www.charlessoft.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Also try [BackupLoupe](http://www.soma-zone.com/BackupLoupe/)

It has the disadvantage compared to TimeTracker that you must have previously mounted the TimeCapsule and the specific backup set you want to browse, while TT does that for you.  But TT was always a little bit unstable on my systems, sometimes failing to dismount volumes when quitting and occasionally failing to work at all until I reinstalled it, and finally, under Snow Leopard, just not working.  However I haven't lost any data with it so it seems safe to try.

Answer (score 0):

Self promotion: `gem install tms` :)